# Google Sheets: Sort Two Columns

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

In a sheet I have two rows that I'd like to sort on:

- ColA: Archived - True/False checkbox
- ColB: SortOrder - number, a way I have at the moment to group things
- Cols C-G: various details

I have a function that does this from a macro, as I'll add a button to the sheet later to run this:

```
function SortServices() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('A1:B').activate();
  ss.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1).sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);
};
```

I'm having a problem, as there are 1000 rows but only ~300 rows currently have data. Of these, about 200 are unchecked and 100 checked (as Archived).  So this sorts the entire colA, then colB, which doesn't correspond to the data cols.

Struggling to explain this, imgs might be better. Here's an example, originally:
[image]

After applying the Sort:

[image]

The issue must be the rows without data, but ColA has checkboxes, which by default are unchecked.  Is there a simple way to get around this? (I don't know much about Sheets)

[Edit] Sorry, should have added what I would like... the rows with no data at the end, same as the first img. When a row is checked as Archived, using Sort would then move it down into the lower section together with other Archived items:

[image]

Comment: In your question, if the upper image is the sample input situation and the bottom image is the sample current output situation, can you provide the sample output situation you expect?

Comment: I believe you need to define your whole data range as a table. Do this by selecting all data and clicking on the filter logo found in the main toolbar

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I've added what I was trying to get, to the post.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Divide the data in two sets and sort in the desired order those that meet the requirements (have data in column B).

### Code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var lr = ss.getLastRow()
  // original values
  var range = ss.getRange(1, 1, lr, 3).getValues()
  // cells without data in colB
  var filtered = range.filter(function (value, index, arr) {
    return value[1] == "";
  });
  // cells with data in colB
  var original = range.filter(x => !filtered.includes(x));
  // write
  ss.getRange(1, 1, original.length, 3).setValues(original).sort([{ column: 1, ascending: true }, { column: 2, ascending: true }]);
  ss.getRange(1 + original.length, 1, filtered.length, 3).setValues(filtered)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought there would be an easier answer, but this works OK:

Inserted a new colA with formula to create a single sortable column:

```
=if( isblank(D2), 20000, if(B2=true, 10000+C2, C2 ) )
```

[image]

Then used this script:

```
function SortServices() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  ss.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, ss.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1).sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
};
```

Probably add this to a custom menu.